# Replace SAS disk for HP ProLiant 380DL Raid1

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp-proliant, sas, raid-controller, replace

I have HP Proliant Server 380DL G9 with 5 SAS disks, (2 disks for raid 1,also 2 disks raid 1 and the last one is raid 0)

one of the disks in the 1st raid 1 is flashing orange, so its recommended to replace the flashing disk with new one.

How to replace this disk, is there any instructions i need to follow and if the controller is hot swappable, how I can make sure that my controller hotswappable function is activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the configuration the first 2 disks are in RAID 1. Means, data mirroring. RAID 1 can sustain 1 drive failure without data loss.
SAS drives will be hot swappable. You can pull the faulty one out and plug the new / replacement one in. The new / replacement drive will rebuild.
This server has p440ar/ 840ar controller to support SAS drives and they does support hot swap functionality.